# While assigning missing values of a factor column in dataframe in R to a particular value

Tags: r

I am trying to replace all the missing values i.e. "" in the column `Nature.of.Usage` of `mydata` dataframe with "Not Identified".

I have tried the following steps

```
levels(mydata$Nature.of.Usage) <- c(levels(mydata$Nature.of.Usage),"Not Identified")

mydata[mydata$Nature.Of.Usage == ""] <- "Not Identified"
```

But i am getting the following error:

> Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, mydata$Nature.of.Usage == "", value
>   = "Not Identified") :    duplicate subscripts for columns

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing a comma as you are selecting a subset of the entire dataframe rather than a subset of the column "Nature.of.Usage".

Try this instead.

```
levels(mydata$Nature.of.Usage) <- c(levels(mydata$Nature.of.Usage),"Not Identified")
mydata[mydata$Nature.Of.Usage == "",] <- "Not Identified"
```

Comment: This is the warning i get
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = c("Not Identified",  ... :
  invalid factor level, NA generated

Comment: Didn't mention it, but you should also apply your first step. I will edit my answer.

Comment: I had applied the first step but still the warning was coming.

Anyways i tried to convert the factor into character column and then tried the same thing,  it worked